# how to use Python hist2D to figure more beautiful？

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

[image]

The left image was drawn using MATLAB and color changing is smooth, beautiful! The right image was drawn using Python matplotlib hist2D and it is sharp.

Is there any method  to make it more beautiful like MATLAB's?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the code that you used for both plots

Comment: Right off the top of my head, the matplotlib points are much bigger, and the MATLAB color scale is linear while the matplotlib color scale is logarithmic.